# K3s - Two pods in the same CIDR subnet doing SNAT in a cluster

Tags: networking, kubernetes, k3s

We have a multi master k3s cluster with etcd. We have launched 2 pods in deployment and both get the IPs from the same CIDR i.e., 10.244.0.xx. cni0 interface ip is 10.244.1.1 on node 1 and 10.244.0.1 on node 2. We use flannel for networking.

Pod 1 IP is 10.244.0.33 and pod 2 IP is 10.244.0.139, when we ping from one pod to the other we see the source IP received on the other side of is cni0 intf IP (10.244.1.1 for ping from p1 to p2).

There is no service involved in this configuration.

How can we avoid this? Is it supposed to perform NATing on the same subnet IP?

What configuration will change this behaviour? Appreciate your early response on this.

Thanks.

Expected behaviour: No SNAT to be done when the communication is between IPs from the same subnet.